# Neural network-development&simulation result&explanation

Tags: r, neural-network, time-series

I've been up to developing a backward propagation(BP) neural network to make a time-series data prediction(past two year data to predict the 3rd one).AMORE package and Neural Network package in R have both been applied and I've got my output in AMORE.However,the big problem is that all my testing samples given the input values finally shared exactly the same outputs,which could really be disastrous.I would paste my codes here,hoping someone would do me a favor.I am really anxious with the explanation and really appreciate your help. Mercy!

```
library(AMORE)
tbincidence<-c(22.37,52.22,73.99,83.51,74.25,79.10,81.19,81.98,80.76,69.29,78.94,80.04,65.80,58.12,116.71,127.01,115.74,116.08,102.58,101.71,94.25,80.27,89.88,89.37,68.37,79.33,113.04,110.72,101.01,102.88,94.41,97.17,88.01,82.37,84.77,86.93,87.80,69.35,107.51,113.10,103.19,102.27,102.16,98.86,90.24,84.33,88.21,90.38,84.49,76.90,118.43,116.34,107.71,99.42,102.91,92.72,93.49,90.30,83.54,91.20,67.86,95.68,105.28,105.19,96.50,106.80,97.26,95.24,93.15,82.00,78.55,90.18,79.31,66.46,103.72,100.13,96.17,95.35,91.61,87.56,83.84,75.73,82.44,78.33,74.26,73.14,101.19,96.31,93.13,88.79,83.77,85.59,79.45,74.57,82.17,77.72,65.21,91.96,102.80,95.35,97.22,87.91,86.85,85.09,78.52,73.98,77.77,72.60,76.95,66.10,92.61,89.73,90.04,78.49,83.61,78.80,77.42,73.74,74.69,73.99,70.57,65.02,82.18,87.19,78.14,74.37,77.50,71.07,70.20,65.12,62.96,67.99,69.54,55.18,82.69,78.82,74.47,74.67,75.07,69.77,69.25,62.63,64.13,65.34,62.70,60.77,83.40,75.24,73.14,68.46,67.54,69.82,65.03,60.49,64.04,65.24,58.91,67.02)
tbincidence
lagtwo<-c(22.37,52.22,73.99,83.51,74.25,79.10,81.19,81.98,80.76,69.29,78.94,80.04,65.80,58.12,116.71,127.01,115.74,116.08,102.58,101.71,94.25,80.27,89.88,89.37,68.37,79.33,113.04,110.72,101.01,102.88,94.41,97.17,88.01,82.37,84.77,86.93,87.80,69.35,107.51,113.10,103.19,102.27,102.16,98.86,90.24,84.33,88.21,90.38,84.49,76.90,118.43,116.34,107.71,99.42,102.91,92.72,93.49,90.30,83.54,91.20,67.86,95.68,105.28,105.19,96.50,106.80,97.26,95.24,93.15,82.00,78.55,90.18,79.31,66.46,103.72,100.13,96.17,95.35,91.61,87.56,83.84,75.73,82.44,78.33,74.26,73.14,101.19,96.31,93.13,88.79,83.77,85.59,79.45,74.57,82.17,77.72,65.21,91.96,102.80,95.35,97.22,87.91,86.85,85.09,78.52,73.98,77.77,72.60,76.95,66.10,92.61,89.73,90.04,78.49,83.61,78.80,77.42,73.74,74.69,73.99,70.57,65.02,82.18,87.19,78.14,74.37,77.50,71.07,70.20,65.12,62.96,67.99,69.54,55.18,82.69,78.82,74.47,74.67,75.07,69.77,69.25,62.63,64.13,65.34,62.70,60.77,83.40,75.24,73.14,68.46,67.54,69.82,65.03,60.49,64.04,65.24)
lagone<-c(52.22,73.99,83.51,74.25,79.10,81.19,81.98,80.76,69.29,78.94,80.04,65.80,58.12,116.71,127.01,115.74,116.08,102.58,101.71,94.25,80.27,89.88,89.37,68.37,79.33,113.04,110.72,101.01,102.88,94.41,97.17,88.01,82.37,84.77,86.93,87.80,69.35,107.51,113.10,103.19,102.27,102.16,98.86,90.24,84.33,88.21,90.38,84.49,76.90,118.43,116.34,107.71,99.42,102.91,92.72,93.49,90.30,83.54,91.20,67.86,95.68,105.28,105.19,96.50,106.80,97.26,95.24,93.15,82.00,78.55,90.18,79.31,66.46,103.72,100.13,96.17,95.35,91.61,87.56,83.84,75.73,82.44,78.33,74.26,73.14,101.19,96.31,93.13,88.79,83.77,85.59,79.45,74.57,82.17,77.72,65.21,91.96,102.80,95.35,97.22,87.91,86.85,85.09,78.52,73.98,77.77,72.60,76.95,66.10,92.61,89.73,90.04,78.49,83.61,78.80,77.42,73.74,74.69,73.99,70.57,65.02,82.18,87.19,78.14,74.37,77.50,71.07,70.20,65.12,62.96,67.99,69.54,55.18,82.69,78.82,74.47,74.67,75.07,69.77,69.25,62.63,64.13,65.34,62.70,60.77,83.40,75.24,73.14,68.46,67.54,69.82,65.03,60.49,64.04,65.24,58.91)
predict<-cbind(lagtwo,lagone)
predict<-matrix(predict,ncol=2,byrow=F)
predict
output<-c(73.99,83.51,74.25,79.10,81.19,81.98,80.76,69.29,78.94,80.04,65.80,58.12,116.71,127.01,115.74,116.08,102.58,101.71,94.25,80.27,89.88,89.37,68.37,79.33,113.04,110.72,101.01,102.88,94.41,97.17,88.01,82.37,84.77,86.93,87.80,69.35,107.51,113.10,103.19,102.27,102.16,98.86,90.24,84.33,88.21,90.38,84.49,76.90,118.43,116.34,107.71,99.42,102.91,92.72,93.49,90.30,83.54,91.20,67.86,95.68,105.28,105.19,96.50,106.80,97.26,95.24,93.15,82.00,78.55,90.18,79.31,66.46,103.72,100.13,96.17,95.35,91.61,87.56,83.84,75.73,82.44,78.33,74.26,73.14,101.19,96.31,93.13,88.79,83.77,85.59,79.45,74.57,82.17,77.72,65.21,91.96,102.80,95.35,97.22,87.91,86.85,85.09,78.52,73.98,77.77,72.60,76.95,66.10,92.61,89.73,90.04,78.49,83.61,78.80,77.42,73.74,74.69,73.99,70.57,65.02,82.18,87.19,78.14,74.37,77.50,71.07,70.20,65.12,62.96,67.99,69.54,55.18,82.69,78.82,74.47,74.67,75.07,69.77,69.25,62.63,64.13,65.34,62.70,60.77,83.40,75.24,73.14,68.46,67.54,69.82,65.03,60.49,64.04,65.24,58.91,67.02)
output<-matrix(output,ncol=1)
output
trainPmatrix<-predict[1:130,]
trainTmatrix<-output[1:130,]
testPmatrix<-predict[131:156,]
testTmatrix<-output[131:156,]
net<-newff(n.neurons=c(2,5,1),learning.rate.global=1e-3,momentum.global=0.5,error.criterium="LMS",Stao=NA,hidden.layer="tansig",output="purelin",method="ADAPTgdwm")
result<-        train(net,trainPmatrix,trainTmatrix,error.criterium="LMS",report=TRUE,show.step=100,n.shows=10)
y<-sim(result$net,testPmatrix)
y
```

The output would be something like this.

```
y
          [,1]
 [1,] 84.81958
 [2,] 84.81958
 [3,] 84.81957
 [4,] 84.81958
 [5,] 84.81958
 [6,] 84.81958
 [7,] 84.81958
 [8,] 84.81958
 [9,] 84.81958
[10,] 84.81958
[11,] 84.81958
[12,] 84.81958
[13,] 84.81958
[14,] 84.81958
[15,] 84.81958
[16,] 84.81958
[17,] 84.81958
[18,] 84.81958
[19,] 84.81958
[20,] 84.81958
[21,] 84.81958
[22,] 84.81958
[23,] 84.81958
[24,] 84.81958
[25,] 84.81958
[26,] 84.81958
```

How could that be possible!!

Thanks a lot for your sharp ideas!

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I used R, and I'm not familiar with AMORE. But, are you normalizing your input in any way? It doesn't look like it. You're using the tansig function for the hidden layer, which returns values between -1 and 1. It might work better if your input were in that range. For time series, you might use the percentage change (expressed as between -1 and 1) from one value to the next instead of the raw values, then scaled if necessary. I'm sure there's a function in an R library which can do that for you. Then, you transform the output in reverse fashion to get the predictions.

You'll probably have to keep tuning the network (learning rate, momentum, etc.), but this might be a place to start.